# Mapping Enum values to Classes

Tags: c#, enums

I want to be able to map each value of an `Enum` to a different `class` (and the reverse), but keep the relationships stored in a single place so they can be altered/added to without making changes in multiple location.

**What pattern would allow me map Enum values to Classes?**

My specific usage is roughly as follows:

I have a `Person` class that holds general information about the person. To this class can be added components (stored in a <s>`List`</s> `Dictionary`) that hold information specific to a particular type of person, eg. `componentCustomer`, `componentEndUser`, `componentSupplier`. These component-classes implement an `IPersonComponent` interface. Importantly, *a person can be more than one type and can therefore hold more than one component*.

I also have an Enum `ePersonType` with values eg. Customer, End User, Supplier. Each value has a one-to-one relationship with a component.

When a person's record is retrieved, a `List<int>` is populated with the appropriate 'ePersonType' values. This list is then used to determine what components need to be allocated to the `Person` and loaded with data.

Clearly, it is straightforward to `switch` on the person's types and add components appropriately. However, what if I later want to check what components the person instance holds and what `ePersonType`s they are? I could `switch` back on `component.GetType()`, but then I am storing the relationship in two places.

Alternatively, I could store the appropriate `ePersonType` inside each component and use Linq to check whether an person instance has a particular component, but then it seems like the original allocation would be more complex, possibly requiring reflection?

I feel sure that I'm missing something really obvious here.

Comment: dictionaries might be good here?

Comment: i think, you need to change your code from using enums to polymorphism https://lostechies.com/johnteague/2013/03/03/polymorphism-part-2-refactoring-to-polymorphic-behavior/

Comment: I can see how to use a Dictionary to map each Enum value to an _instance_ of the classes, but I'm not sure how to do it to the class itself?

Comment: General sense of enum (in every programming language having) is quite static thing (i.e. association yes but constant). Of-course there is possible encapsulate into enum dynamic reality, but seems in wrong style. If I would to implement such idea in C# - extension methods seems best. But read comments, idea is quite bad

Answer (score 4):

One of the ways I've approached this is to use an attribute on the actual enum values:

```
public enum PersonType
{
  [PersonClass(typeof(Customer)]
  Customer,

  [PersonClass(typeof(EndUser)]
  EndUser,

  [PersonClass(typeof(Supplier)]
  Supplier,
}

public class PersonClassAttribute : System.Attribute 
{
    public Type Type { get; }

    public PersonClassAttribute(Type type)
    {
        Type = type;
    }
}
```

Then use a static class for managing the retrieval and mapping of enums to types:

```
public static class People
{
    static Dictionary<PersonType, Type> mapping = new Dictionary<PersonType, Type>();

    static People()
    {
        var fields = Enum.GetNames(typeof(PersonType)).Select(n => typeof(PersonType).GetFieldr(n));
        mapping = fields.ToDictionary(
            f => (PersonType)f.GetRawConstantValue(),
            f => f.GetCustomAttribute<PersonClassAttribute>().Type
            );
    }


    public static T GetPersonInstance<T>(this PersonType type)
    {
       return (T)Activator.CreateInstance(mapping[type]);
    }
}
```

Obviously there'd be a bit more to it (validation, error checking, etc), but that's the general idea.